# Почему в таблице при `border-collapse: separate` не отображается border-top у thead?

Tags: html, css

Если я ставлю параметр `border-collapse: collapse`, то border - видно. Чем регулируется это поведение?

```css
table { 
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
thead {
 border-top: solid 1px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
   <thead>
     <tr> 
      <th>&nbsp;</th><th>2013</th>
      <th>2014</th><th>2015</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr> 
      <td>Нефть</td><td>43</td>
      <td>51</td><td>79</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>Золото</td><td>29</td>
      <td>34</td><td>48</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>Дерево</td><td>38</td>
      <td>57</td><td>36</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Иначе:

```css
table { width: 100%; border-collapse: separate; }
thead { border-top: solid 1px; }
```

```html
<table>
   <thead>
     <tr> 
      <th>&nbsp;</th><th>2013</th>
      <th>2014</th><th>2015</th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr> 
      <td>Нефть</td><td>43</td>
      <td>51</td><td>79</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>Золото</td><td>29</td>
      <td>34</td><td>48</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>Дерево</td><td>38</td>
      <td>57</td><td>36</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`border-collapse` - устанавливает, как отображать границы вокруг ячеек таблицы.

[`collapse`] - линия между ячейками отображается только одна.

[`separate`] - вокруг каждой ячейки отображается своя собственная рамка, в местах соприкосновения ячеек показываются сразу две линии.

Так как явно не задан цвет границы, то при `collapse`(должна отобразиться одна граница) взят цвет по умолчанию (black) и отображается граница в `table`, а не в `thead`. Учитывается `border` в `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` и `tr`.

При `separate` игнорируются `border` в `thead`, `tbody`, `tfoot` и `tr`.